# Generate a random double between -1 and 1 in Swift

Tags: swift

This one should be quite simple but somehow I can't find a way to do this:
 I have to get a random double between -1 and 1.

Everything I found on the internet was either for Integers, from 0 to 1 or didn't work.

I hope some of you guys can help me!

Comment: If you can generate a random `Double` between 0 and 1, then you can just double it and subtract 1 for a random value between -1 and 1.

Comment: create a random from 0 to 2, then subtract 1.

Comment: You don't know how to multiply it by 2 and subtract 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let a = (Double(arc4random()) / Double(UInt32.max)) * 2 - 1
```

PS: use UInt32.max for a Swifty code ;)

Comment: `UInt32.max` is more Swifty than `UINT32_MAX` :)

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was searching for. Strangely I couldn't find this on the internet :)